# How to rerender multiple charts

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender, visualforce-charting

I'm trying to rerender two apex chart components after a form field change, and can only seem to rerender one of them.

Here's my page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="chartTestCtrl">
    <style>
        .chartContainer {
            width: 700px;
            background: #57b6dd;
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .chartContainer h1, .chartContainer h2 {
            display: block;
            color: #000;
        }
        .chartContainer h1 {
            padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    </style>
    <apex:form id="chartsForm">
        <apex:outputPanel id="charts">
            <apex:repeat value="{!charts}" var="chart">
                <div class="chartContainer">
                    <h1>
                        Chart {!chart.chartNumber}
                    </h1>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!chart.chartNumber}">
                        <!-- Subsituting any of the below actionSupport components does not change the result -->
                        <!-- <apex:actionSupport action="{!doSomething}"
                                event="onchange"
                                reRender="{!Component.charts}"/> -->
                        <!-- <apex:actionSupport action="{!doSomething}"
                                event="onchange"
                                reRender="charts"/> -->
                        <!-- <apex:actionSupport action="{!doSomething}"
                                event="onchange"
                                reRender="chartsForm"/> -->
                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!doSomething}"
                                event="onchange"
                                reRender="{!$Component.chartsForm}"/>
                    </apex:inputText>
                    <span id='chart-{!chart.chartNumber}'>&nbsp;</span>
                    <apex:chart height="400" width="700" legend="true" data="{!chart.data}"
                                renderto="chart-{!chart.chartNumber}" rendered="true">
                        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="category"/>
                        <apex:axis type="Numeric" minimum="0" maximum="5" position="left" fields="value"/>
                        <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" title="Bar Series" axis="bottom" 
                                xField="category" yField="value"/>
                    </apex:chart>
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and my controller:

```
public with sharing class chartTestCtrl {

    private static Integer COUNT = 0;

    public List<Chart> charts {get;set;}

    public chartTestCtrl() {
        charts = new List<Chart> {
            new Chart(),
            new Chart()
        };
    }

    public void doSomething() { }

    public class Chart {
        public Integer chartNumber {get;set;}
        public List<Data> data {get;set;}

        public Chart() {
            COUNT++;
            chartNumber = COUNT;
            data = new List<Data> {new Data()};
        }
    }

    public class Data {
        public String category {get;set;}
        public Integer value {get; set;}

        public Data() {
            category = 'C ' + COUNT;
            value = COUNT;
        }
    }
}
```

And the resulting output:

[image: initial]

Output after changing the first chart form field to '3':

[image: first form field changed]

Output after changing the second chart form field to '4':

[image]

The rerender seems to be only able to generate one chart, and that's the chart closes to the actionSupport component. How do I modify the page/controller so both charts can be rerendered?

Comment: the `doSomething()` -- does it iterate through both charts in chartList and refresh with data based on the value of `chartNumber` ? Perhaps that is where the problem lies

Comment: The doSomething() method doesn't do anything! All the information required to rerender both charts is always available, but only one chart is ever rerendered.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood - I thought you were cycling through various charts that were dynamically constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to currently be a known issue with charts and the `apex:repeat` tag. The [known issues article](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2AUAA0) in the salesforce success community identifies a workaround for the problem to fall back to some raw html.

However you appear to have tried that workaround and it still fails.

I have copied your code and have tried numerous variations to get it to work based on the proposed workaround, but I am not having any success.

Bottom line. I think this is a bug. And if the workaround ever worked, it doesn't appear to anymore. Please file a case with support. If you are a developer not affiliated with a customer org, you can post this to the developer forums and developer support will rase a case from there.

Comment: nice!  although I didn't see  the raw HTML attempt in OP (there is still a repeat)

Comment: `<span id='chart-{!chart.chartNumber}'>&nbsp;</span>` is intended to be the place that the `apex:chart` component is set to render to. I tried multiple variants of that, with `span` and `div` tags. Fixed `renderTo` to be case-sensitive, and even subbed different iterating components like `dataTable` and `pageBlockTable`. No love on anything I tried.

Comment: I've posted it to the forms here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000MIMS. In my case I was able to put the charts in an iframe and refresh the whole page, which does seem to work. In general I think JS Remoting would be a better approach: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data_javascript_remoting.htm

Answer (score 3):

The `reRender` attribute takes a literal, comma-delimited set of id's.

```
reRender="thiscomponent,thatcomponent,theothercomponent"
```

In your case, I would think you could simply do the following:

```
reRender="charts"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the results seem to be the same.